# Unable to loop through the data to print charts using charts.js in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am new to Javascript and I have been stuck with this since some time now. I am trying to loop through the dataframe which I get from flask and I am trying to generate bar charts w.r.t the columns present in the dataframe. (I am using a sample data here though I am converting the dataframe to list in my original code).

But I am only getting one chart w.r.t the first element of the itemData. Where am I going wrong here? Is it related to the canvas being created only once? Your help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```js
let labels = ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6'];

let itemData = [
  [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
  [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
  [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [10, 11, 12, 13.14, 15],
  [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]
];

let text = ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6'];

for (let i = 0; i < itemData.length; i++) {
  const data = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      data: itemData[i],
      backgroundColor: 'green'
    }]
  };

  const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: text[i]
        }
      }
    }
  };

  const chart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart'),
    config
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.3.2/chart.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-ziISJqd7FOx3QNvnXiFWAfgSKqte9jMjzhrCnc7Gxpxfxjb5FdrBFg673DloeFEH6VLmTeo86yu5y/xJm38cBg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
</script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <p><a href="/" class="btn btn-secondary btn">Back to Charts & Analysis</a></p>

  <h4>Feature-wise Analysis</h4>
  <hr>
</div>


<div style="padding-left: 100px; width: 600px; height: 500px;">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. You have divs outside the body.

You cannot have the new Chart in the same canvas

```js
const container = document.getElementById('chartContainer')
const labels = ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6'];

const itemData = [
  [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
  [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
  [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [10, 11, 12, 13.14, 15],
  [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]
];

const text = ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6'];
// create a default config
const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
      }
    }
  }
};


for (let i = 0; i < itemData.length; i++) {
  config.data = { // change this chart's config
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      data: itemData[i],
      backgroundColor: 'green'
    }]
  };

  config.options.plugins.title.text = text[i]; // change this chart's title
  
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas'); // create a new canvas
  container.appendChild(canvas); // and append it
  const chart = new Chart(canvas, config);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.3.2/chart.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-ziISJqd7FOx3QNvnXiFWAfgSKqte9jMjzhrCnc7Gxpxfxjb5FdrBFg673DloeFEH6VLmTeo86yu5y/xJm38cBg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
</script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <p><a href="/" class="btn btn-secondary btn">Back to Charts & Analysis</a></p>

  <h4>Feature-wise Analysis</h4>
  <hr>
</div>


<div id="chartContainer" style="padding-left: 100px; width: 600px; height: 500px;">

</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks, @mplungjan! I am trying to learn both html and javascript by directly working on a personal project. I am able to figure out most of the things with some help online, and few are very difficult to resolve. Thanks once again for highlighting some fundamental issues and providing a resolution. Highly appreciate your support!!